# Control losing focus when changing selected tab programatically

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a textbox & a tabcontrol in my interface. I have tried to set the focus to the textbox & then change the selected tab index via the code. The textbox seems to get the focus however as soon as I change the selected tab index textbox loses its focus.

Here is the code.

```
mytextbox1.Focus() '//Setting the focus to the textbox
tabcontrol1.SelectedIndex = 0 '//This makes the mytextbox1 lose its focus.
```

I can't change these two lines the other way around because they are executed along with different functions. Is there a easy way to change the tabcontrol selected index without changing the focus.

Answer (score 0):

why not reverse it?

```
tabcontrol1.SelectedIndex = 0
mytextbox1.Focus()
```